# Cannot get scrolling on zoomed in image to work

Tags: java, android, scroll, imageview

I have an `ImageView` that I can use to zoom in on an image, but I cannot get the image to scroll. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong by looking at my code?

Here's my `activity_route_detail.xml` with the `ImageView` I'm trying to scroll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zach.listview.RouteDetails">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeImage"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my `routeDetails.java` with the scroll code:

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class RouteDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Float scale = 1f;
    ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
    ImageView routeImage;

    //variables for scrolling
    float curX, curY;
    float mx;
    float my;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);

        //back button for route details view
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //TextView for route details
        final TextView routeDetailsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeDetailsView);
        routeDetailsView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("route"));

        //ImageView for route details
        routeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.routeImage);
        routeImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("imageResourceId", 0));



        ///// scrolling listener code

        routeDetailsView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {



                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mx = event.getX();
                        my = event.getY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        curX = event.getX();
                        curY = event.getY();
                        routeDetailsView.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                        mx = curX;
                        my = curY;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        curX = event.getX();
                        curY = event.getY();
                        routeDetailsView.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });



        /////



        SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
    }

    //listener for pinch zoom
    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
         public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scale = scale * detector.getScaleFactor();
            scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5f));
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            routeImage.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    //back button for route details view
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` will not turn itself into a scrolled view when it is scaled out using the matrix.

You have to use the matrix itself to move the scaled `ImageView` to the desired location, something like this:

```
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale)
            matrix.postTranslate(curX - mx, curY - my);
            routeImage.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Then you need to do two additional things:

- You need to keep track of the current scale factor you are using so you can set the matrix to the proper scale value as well as translation values.
- You will need to do some bounds checking so that if the user tries to scroll the image inside of a view bound, you adjust the scroll to keep the image on the view bound so you don't get a big empty space.  Warning: Getting all the checking and adjusting correct is a real pain in the butt. I wrote one of these zoom components, and it's not as simple as it sounds.

Also, I noticed you are calling `matrix.setScale(scale, scale)` in your `ScaleListener`. In order to get the scale to work in tandem with the scrolling, you should call `getFocusX()` and `getFocusY()` on the detector, then you can do

```
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale, focusX, focusY)
```

That leaves you with an additional challenge, which is finding out where the current image bounds are in relationship to the view bounds.  I kept a `Rect` with the original dimensions of the image and used `matrix.mapRect()` after scaling to get the updated image bounds.  And of course, you will have to do the same bounds checking and adjusting for the image edge going inside the view.

---

There are a ton of these image view implementations on GitHub.  You might save yourself some time & agony by searching GitHub for "Touch Image View" or "Zoom Image View" and using a pre-coded (and hopefully pre-tested) component.